# Periodic cron-like Functions Across Containers in a Docker Project

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have implemented the LAMP stack for a 3rd party forum application on its own dedicated virtual server.  One of my aims here was to use a composed docker project (under Git) to encapsulate the application fully.  I wanted to keep this as simple to understand as possible for the other sysAdmins supporting the forum, so this really ruled out using `S6` etc., and this in turn meant that I had to stick to the standard of one container per daemon service using the docker runtime to do implement the daemon functionality.

I had one particular design challenge that doesn't seem to be addressed cleanly through the Docker runtime system, and that is I need to run periodic housekeeping activities that need to interact across various docker containers, for example:

- The forum application requires a per-minute PHP housekeeping task to be run using `php-cli`, and I only have `php-cli` and `php-fpm` (which runs as the foreground deamon process) installed in the `php` container.
- Letsencrypt certificate renewal need a weekly `certbot` script to be run in the apache container's file hierarchy.
- I use conventional `/var/log` based logging for high-volume Apache access logs as these generate Gb access files that I want to retain for ~7 days in the event of needing to do hack analysis, but that are otherwise ignored.

Yes I could use the hosts crontab to run `docker exec` commands but this involves exposing application internals to the host system and IMO this is breaking one of my design rules.  What follows is my approach to address this.  My Q is really to ask for comments and better alternative approaches, and if not then this can perhaps serve as a template for others searching for an approach to this challenge.

- All of my containers contain two special to container scripts: `docker-entrypoint.sh` which is a well documented convention; `docker-service-callback.sh` which is the action mechanism to implement the tasking system.
- I have one application agnostic host service [systemctl: docker-callback-reader.service](https://github.com/TerryE/docker-buildhub/blob/main/conf/docker-callback-reader.service) which uses this bash script, [docker-callback-reader](https://github.com/TerryE/docker-buildhub/blob/main/bin/docker-callback-reader).  This services requests on a `/run` pipe that is volume-mapped into any container that need to request such event processes.
- In practice I have only one such housekeeping container [see here](https://github.com/TerryE/docker-buildhub/tree/main/service/hk) that implements Alpine crond and runs all of the cron-based events. So for example the following entry does the per-minute PHP tasking call:

```
 -  *  *  *  *  echo ${VHOST} php task >/run/host-callback.pipe
```

- In this case the `env` variable `VHOST` identifies the relevant docker stack, as I can have multiple instances (`forum` and `test`) running on the server; the next parameter (`php` in this case) identifies the destination service container; the final parameter (`task`) plus any optional parameters are passed as arguments to a `docker exec` of `php` containers `docker-service-callback.sh` and magic happens as required.

I feel that the strengths of the system are that:

- Everything is suitably encapsulated.  The host knows nothing of the internals of the app other than any receiving container must have a `docker-service-callback.sh` on its execution path.  The details of each request are implemented internally in the executing container, and are hidden from the tasking container.
- The whole implementation is simple, robust and has minimal overhead.
- Anyone is free to browse my Git repo and cherry-pick  whatever of this they wish.

Comments?

Comment: Kubernetes is much heavier-weight than the infrastructure you describe here, but it includes a CronJob object that can launch a container on a schedule and that would fit many of these needs.

Comment: @DavidMaze, thanks for the feedback.  I was aware of the Kubernetes

Comment: and its cronjob functionality, but IMO even though there's a lot of functional overlap between Kubernetes and Docker Compose their target environments are quite disjoint as you comment.  Here I've a single dedicated virtual server running a forum application suite and I don't think Kubernetes is a good fit for this usecase.